# How to use IdentityServer4 scopes in resource api

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am creating an api resource in my identityserver application:

```
new ApiResource
{
    Name = "socialnetwork",

    Scopes =
    {
        new Scope()
        {
            Name = "socialnetwork.read_contents",
            DisplayName = "Read"
        },
        new Scope
        {
            Name = "socialnetwork.share_content",
            DisplayName = "Write"
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I use this scopes in my socialnetwork api controllers.

```
public class SocialController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetCotntents(){

   }

   [HttpPost]       
   public async Task<IActionResult> ShareCotntents(string content){

   }
}
```

- If a client has `socialnetwork.read_contents` scope, it can access `GetCotntents()` method.
- If a client has `socialnetwork.share_content` scope, it can access `ShareCotntents()` method.

Actually does scope purpose is this? And how can I use it?

Answer (score 5):

I believe that what you need to do is set up a policy for each scope you want to use (in your ConfigureServices)

```
 services.AddAuthorization(x =>
            {
                x.AddPolicy("readcontents", policy => 
                  policy.RequireClaim("scope", "socialnetwork.read_contents"));
                x.AddPolicy("shared", policy => 
                 policy.RequireClaim("scope", "socialnetwork.share_content"));
            });
```

Add then you can mark the Authorize attribute on your api method with the policy

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Authorize("readcontents")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetCotntents(){

   }

  [HttpPost]      
  [Authorize("shared")] 
  public async Task<IActionResult> ShareCotntents(string content){

  }
```

Comment: Can I add multiple polycy in one attribute? [Authorize("shared,readcontents")]